# Parsing a header file using swig

Tags: python, swig

I have a header file with struct definitions that I'd like to be able to parse in python. In order to do this I turned to Swig.

Lets say the header file is named "a.h". I first renamed it to "a.c" and added an empty "a.h" file in the same folder.

Next, I added in an "a_wrap.i" file with the following contents.

```
%module a
%{
    /* the resulting C file should be built as a python extension */
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    /*  Includes the header in the wrapper code */
    #include "a.h"
%}
/*  Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
%include "a.h"
extern struct a_a;
extern struct a_b;
extern struct a_c;
```

Next, I wrote a setup.py file as follows :

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(ext_modules=[Extension("_a",
      sources=["a.c", "a_wrap.i"])])
```

Next, I did the build as

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I finally tried to import it in python

```
>>> import a # it works, yaay
>>> dir(a)
...
...
```

I was hoping for a way to access the structs defined in "a.c"(originally a.h). However, I don't seem to be able to find a way to do that. How can I solve this? I'm looking for a way to access the struct's defined in the header file from python.

Comment: Renaming arbitrary header files to c files seems dangerous, given that convention usually leads to matching .c and .h file names.  Are you sure you can do that without deleting a bunch of code?

Comment: Just include your original header. If there is any issues, remember SWIG cannot recurse headers so declarations must be in order. Also, export keywords and other stuff are not understood. This can be fixed by including `%include "windows.s" if on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The global variables `a_a`, `a_b and`a_c`should be accessible from [within your SWIG Python module via`cvar`][1](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn16):

```
import a
print a.cvar.a_a
print a.cvar.a_b
# etc.
```